# Hierarchical logistic regression package in R

Tags: r, regression, logistic, multilevel-analysis

I'm working on a logistic regression model; the purpose of the analysis is to identify factors that influence use of an app - the DV being use/no use, and IVs being a couple of numerical and categorical variables.

I want to do a hierarchical regression and add variables step-wise, and compare how much each variable improves the model.
At the moment I define multiple models, add a variable for each model, compare the models using an ANOVA and save and compare the (adjusted) R squares in a table:

```
model1 <- glm(mh_use ~ Q7, data = results_mod, family = "binomial")
model2 <- glm(mh_use ~ Q7 + Q6_4_TEXT, data = results_mod, family = "binomial")
model3 <- glm(mh_use ~ Q7 + Q6_4_TEXT + Q66, data = results_mod, family = "binomial")
anova(model1, model2, model3, test= "Chisq")

rtbl <- matrix(nrow = 3, ncol = 2, byrow = TRUE)
rtbl[1,] <- c(rsq(model1), rsq(model1,adj=TRUE))
rtbl[2,] <- c(rsq(model2), rsq(model2,adj=TRUE))
rtbl[3,] <- c(rsq(model3), rsq(model3,adj=TRUE))
```

Rather than doing this manually, I was wondering if there is a package/function in R that does this for you and gives the relevant results? And is R squared the best comparison for logistic regression or should I include other measures?

Answer (score 0):

OK, so:

1. I don't think this is hierarchical logistic regression.  The word "hierarchical" is sometimes used to refer to random/mixed effects models (because parameters sit in a hierarchichy).  This is just logistic regression.
2. R square is not a good way to compare logistic regression models.  It depends on what you're interested in studying, but a generalized r squared (like Nagelkerke's R squared) are better.

Is your goal here to infer some effect or are you trying to predict something?

Comment: thanks! the goal is inference, not predict.

Comment: OK, goal is inference.  What about the model is trying to be "improved"?  I'm assuming the generalized R squared?  More generally, I think something like AIC might be a good tool here (though I'm personally not a fan of AIC but that is another story).

Comment: The improvement is to evaluate how much additional variance is explained by adding each variable, so yes something like generalized R squared (or another suitable measure).

Comment: If this starts looking like stepwise regression beware.  And the data are seldom capable of telling you how important each predictor is.  That takes an enormous dataset.